# Hello world error in opendaylight

Tags: maven, opendaylight

**I am trying to implement the hello world in ODL-mdsal, "under a different name qos". I followed two different procedures in [link1](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Controller_Core_Functionality_Tutorials:Application_Development_Tutorial) and [link2](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html).**   but got the same error in both.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-api ............. SUCCESS [  8.455 s] 
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-impl ............ SUCCESS [  3.612 s]
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-cli ............. SUCCESS [  3.268 s]
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-features ........ FAILURE [01:30 min]
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-karaf ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-artifacts ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-it .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] qos ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project qos-features: There are test failures.
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/qos/features/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :qos-features
```

**I did not change anything in the feature folder, my maven project is build using the following command.** I first used the oomph installer with the integration project to set the needed plugins, then I added my project as an existing maven project.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId= org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.0-Carbon
```

Comment: this could help ?? SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/org.apache.karaf.client/3.0.8/org.apache.karaf.client-3.0.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.4/pax-logging-api-1.8.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/ghalwash/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify for anyone else, the `org.opendaylight.qos` is not an Opendaylight.org project but just the name you gave when using the archetype.

The broken `features` build seems to be because the released (old) `archetypeVersion=1.3.0-Carbon` seems to be broken.  Have you considered just using the latest one?

Make sure that you have the ODL settings.xml, and then just:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
    -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: do I need to define a repository ?   -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/

Comment: @Haitham normally not, no but hope you saw here how to get the custom Maven settings.xml required by ODL, on https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup#Edit_your_.7E.2F.m2.2Fsettings.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the snapshot and public URLs in my setting.xml, Thank you so much for your help